# Context does not contain a definition for FragmentManager

Tags: c#, android, fragmentmanager

Im getting the abvove error, why? Im using it inside an adapter, which cannot give me the activity via property `Activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction`. I passed the context into the constructor and im getting the error.

```
Button buttonAddExercise = row.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonAddExercise);
buttonAddExercise.Click += delegate {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = myContext.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
};

public DayObject(Context context, List<Fragments.Day> items) {
    myItems = items;
    myContext = context;
}
```

Comment: Try to change "Context context" to "Activity context"

Comment: It worked! Thanks.